# How to set wave effect for a button when taps on it in Flutter

Tags: flutter, animation

[image]

Hi, I was trying to build this ui, but i couldnt implement the wave effect as shown in the image.
i got some code for the wave effect but it does not fit well. I made the ui code very complex. so i made a similar ui for sharing .
///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
//////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
/////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

```
class Test extends StatefulWidget {
  const Test({Key key}) : super(key: key);

      @override
      _TestState createState() => _TestState();
     }

     class _TestState extends State<Test> {
      @override
      Widget build(BuildContext context) {
       return Scaffold(
       backgroundColor: AppColors.mainBg3,
     body: Center(
     child: Column(
      mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
      children: [
        buttonView(0),
        buttonView(1),
        buttonView(2),
        buttonView(4),
      ],
    ),
  ),
);
 }

var selectedIndex = 0;

  Widget buttonView(int i) {
  return Container(
  margin: EdgeInsets.only(bottom: 30),
  child: InkWell(
    onTap: () {
      selectedIndex = i;
      setState(() {

      });
    },
    child: selectedIndex == i ? WaveAnimation(child: button()) : button(),
  ),
);
 }

 Widget button() {
  return Row(
  mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
  children: [
    CircleAvatar(
      radius: 12,
      backgroundColor: Colors.white,
      child: Container(
        height: 13,
        width: 13,
        decoration: BoxDecoration(
            shape: BoxShape.circle,
            gradient: LinearGradient(
                colors: [Color(0xffD053A3), Color(0xff842990)])),
              ),
            ),
          ],
         );
        }
       }
```

And heres the code of wave animation

```
class WaveAnimation extends StatefulWidget {
const WaveAnimation({
  this.size = 80.0,
  @required this.child,
});
final double size;
final Widget child;

@override
_WaveAnimationState createState() => _WaveAnimationState();
}

class _WaveAnimationState extends State<WaveAnimation>
  with TickerProviderStateMixin {
AnimationController _controller;

@override
void initState() {
  super.initState();
  _controller = AnimationController(
    duration: const Duration(milliseconds: 2000),
    vsync: this,
  );
}

@override
void dispose() {
  _controller.dispose();
  super.dispose();
}

Color _color = Color(0xffB05CA1);

@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
  return Center(
      child: CustomPaint(
        painter: CirclePainter(
          _controller,
          color: _color.withOpacity(0.1),
        ),
        child: SizedBox(
          width: widget.size * 2,
          height: widget.size * 2,
          child: _button(),
        ),
      ),
    );
}

Widget _button() {
  return Center(
    child: ClipRRect(
      borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(widget.size),
      child: DecoratedBox(
        decoration: BoxDecoration(
          gradient: RadialGradient(
            colors: <Color>[_color, Color.lerp(_color, Colors.black, 0.05)],
          ),
        ),
        child: ScaleTransition(
          scale: Tween(begin: 0.95, end: 1.0).animate(
            CurvedAnimation(
              parent: _controller,
              curve: CurveWave(),
            ),
          ),
        ),
      ),
    ),
  );
}
}

class CurveWave extends Curve {
const CurveWave();

@override
double transform(double t) {
  if (t == 0 || t == 1) {
    return 0.01;
  }
  return math.sin(t * math.pi);
}
}

class CirclePainter extends CustomPainter {
CirclePainter(
  this._animation, {
  @required this.color,
}) : super(repaint: _animation);
final Color color;
final Animation<double> _animation;

void circle(Canvas canvas, Rect rect, double value) {
  final double opacity = (1.0 - (value / 4.0)).clamp(0.0, 0.2);
  final Color _color = color.withOpacity(opacity);
  final double size = rect.width / 2;
  final double area = size * size;
  final double radius = math.sqrt(area * value / 4);
  final Paint paint = Paint()..color = _color;
  canvas.drawCircle(rect.center, radius, paint);
}

@override
void paint(Canvas canvas, Size size) {
  final Rect rect = Rect.fromLTRB(0.0, 0.0, size.width, size.height);
  for (int wave = 3; wave >= 0; wave--) {
    circle(canvas, rect, wave + _animation.value);
  }
}

@override
bool shouldRepaint(CirclePainter oldDelegate) => true;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

To fit this effect you will use customBorder inside the inkwell.

```
customBorder:StadiumBorder()
```